# How to make the array read from a textfile?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm new to `PHP` and i'm trying to build a type of generator. I started off with hard coding the different array values. So everything that's between "( )" is what I'm going to store in a text file. However I can't see how I should do it.

Ex. `$num = array (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);`
The numbers 0-9 is what i want array to get from a textfile instead.
Same with `$spec = array ('!','#','%','&','?');`

Here is how i've done it now:

```
<?php 
    $pass = array();
    $verb = array ('Klappa', 'Springande','Bakande', 'Badande',
    'Cyklande', 'Jagande', 'Skrattande', 'Flygande', 'Simmande','Gissande');
    $num = array (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
    $sub = array ('katt', 'hund','fisk', 'padda', 'lama', 'tiger','panda', 'lejon', 'djur', 'telefon');
    $spec = array ('!','#','%','&','?');
    $pass[] = $verb[array_rand($verb)];
    for($i=0;$i<1;$i++){
        $pass[] = $num[array_rand($num)];
    }
    $pass[] = $sub[array_rand($sub)];
    for($i=0;$i<1;$i++){
        $pass[] = $spec[array_rand($spec)];
    }
    //shuffle($pass);
    foreach($pass as $p){
        $password .= $p;
    }
    // echo "$password <br>";
?>
```

I don't want `('!','#','%','&','?');` to be shown in the code, also to be read from a text file. What should I do?

Comment: I don't see where you tried to read something from textfile

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing to a file, you could:

```
<?php
    foreach(range(0,9) as $number){
        $output .= $number . PHP_EOL;
    }

    file_put_contents('textfile.txt', $output);

?>
```

which will output to textfile.txt in the following format:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

to read that back into an array, you can then

```
<?php

    $input = file_get_contents('textfile.txt');

    $num = [];
    $num = explode(PHP_EOL,$input);

    //Take the blank element off the end of the array
    array_pop($num);

    echo '<pre>';
        print_r($num);
    echo '</pre>';

?>
```

which will give you the output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 5
    [6] => 6
    [7] => 7
    [8] => 8
    [9] => 9
)
```

to read the numbers you can then call

```
<?php

    foreach($num as $number){
        //You can do whatever you want here, but i'm just going to print number
        echo $number;
    }

?>
```

which will give you

```
0123456789
```

I'm aware there are simpler methods, but doing this way so OP can see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create your file, and insert the characters you want line by line.
You can use this code snippet to read the file and insert your values into an array:

```
<?php
    $handle = @fopen("/file.txt", "r");
    //declare your array here
    if ($handle) {
        while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
            //add $buffer to your array.
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
?>
```

You may want to look at [this as a reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php).